# Add Survey in custom object call

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I have a requirement where i have to add survey functionality in call record (call is a custom object). Survey fillup will be mandatory for call submission. Can the Salesforce vanila survey feature be invoked from inside each call record? And will survey response be captured for each call record?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of blog posts on sending surveys triggered on any object. My favorite is https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/send-salesforce-survey-without-writing-code/ - give it a shot and see how it goes.

Or use the Send Survey action in Process Builder. That is documented in the Survey section of the online Salesforce help.